# Dynamic data type casting in C++

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

I am working on a DLL that uses a fixed set of 10 data types: unsigned/signed integers of 8/16/32/64-bit and floats of 32/64-bit.

I receive a void pointer to a buffer from the client along with an enum representing the data type. I then have to look at the data type enum supplied to know what data type to cast the buffer to in order to extract the value.

Example:

```
nU8Val  = (*(U8*)pvBuffer);
nU16Val = (*(U16*)pvBuffer);
nU32Val = (*(U32*)pvBuffer);
```

Is there any way to combine this logic into a single line such as:

```
nMyVal = *((TypeOf(nMyVal)*)pvBuffer);
```

Where I don't need to define variables for all data types and repeat the same logic for each data type enumeration

EDIT: I updated the example logic for clarity on what I was trying to do as far as casting the void* buffer to a pointer of the receiving variable's data type

Comment: You can't do it dynamically,but you can use some template code. But to give an answer/suggestion there is a piece missing: what do you want to do with the result?

Comment: I need to compare the result against defined limit values. I have a data point which has a MAX and MIN value, I receive a new piece of data for that point via void* and need to extract it based on data type and assure that it is within the bounds of the MIN and MAX

Comment: Adding a C++ interface to your `.dll` could solve the problem naturally.

Comment: Okay I'll read over some documentation for that. Thank you for the quick responses.

Comment: no, you can't. The only way I can think of, is to have a class handling the conversion, and storing the value for different types as a double. That means you'll convert every value n input to a double, not the best solution around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a template that can deduce the type from the assignee, so that you don't have to repeat it:

```
template<typename To>
void copy_deduced(void* from, To& to) {
    to = *reinterpret_cast<To*>(from); // avoid c-style casts
}
copy_deduced(pvBuffer, nU8Val);
// ...
```

Comment: `memcpy(&to, from, sizeof to);` will achieve the same effect but without potentially violating the strict aliasing rule

Comment: Template solved my issue. I was able to create a comparison function utilizing a template for data type, and then cast the void pointer buffers being passed into the function to whatever type I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that it's already in a dynamic type, namely void*. What I would do, if I understand your problem correctly, is create a struct with a void* (I would allocate a new block) and an enumeration value representing the data type. Then, use a switch statement to decide among very similar pieces of code when using the values. You can't simply cast everything to some 64-bit type such as double or unsigned long long, as is suggested in comments, because that could result in an unauthorized member l memory access error if the allocation is less than 8 bytes, which is quite conceivable, since 70% of the possible types are smaller than that.

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone was suggesting casting everything to a 64-bit type. The logic I currently use is already a switch statement which casts the data based on the data type enum value. My question was to see if there was a way to dynamically cast the data in a void* buffer into the data type of the variable receiving the result of the cast

Comment: In that case, the obvious solution would be templates, as suggested in the last answer. However, if you don't want to use templates, for example if you want to expose a C api, or you want to limit to your whitelist of types, you'll either be stuck with something like what I have suggested, or just raw void pointers.